# Rotating Y axis to flip Texture facing inverts X axis

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, rotational-matrices, transformation-matrix

I want to rotate my sprites (applying the rotation to the transformation matrix) along the Y axis to flip the direction of the sprite.

But it somehow seems like it also affects my inputs system...
Pressing right becomes left... And it seems that the sprite is no longer rendered at the entity real position.. The "real position" is ruled by the inputs system and followed by the camera, but the sprite goes the opposite way, as if inputs were inverted. *(inputs change the velocity corresponding to the key pressed and the transform component is translate by this vector each update)*

Here's the code i use to get the matrices :

```
    public Matrix4f getTransformationMatrix() {
            Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
            matrix.scale(scale);
            matrix.rotateX((float) Math.toRadians(rotation.getX()));
            matrix.rotateY((float) Math.toRadians(rotation.getY()));
            matrix.rotateZ((float) Math.toRadians(rotation.getZ()));
            matrix.translate(position);
            return matrix;
        }
    
       
        public Matrix4f getViewMatrix() {
            Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
            matrix.rotateZ((float) Math.toRadians(rotation.getZ()));
            matrix.translate(Vector3f.scale(position, -1));
            return matrix;
        }
```

I have check and re-check my rotations matrix but affraid over confidence here they are :

```
X = new Matrix4f(new float[][] { {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, cos, -sin, 0}, {0, sin, cos, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1} })
Y = new Matrix4f(new float[][] { {cos, 0, sin, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {-sin, 0, cos, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1} })
Z = new Matrix4f(new float[][] { {cos, sin, 0, 0}, {-sin, cos, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1} })
```

I use the mvp matrices in my shader in that order `projection_matrix * view_matrix * transformation_matrix * vec4(attribute_position, 1.0)`.

Comment: From which library came your Matrix4f? Because if it's JOML you already have a method to do rotation translation and scaling in one time. Also if you rotate on the 3 axis, use Quaternion instead of euler angles. Because with euler angle you got an issue and you "lost" an axis.

Comment: It's my own class, i needed to understand what i was manipulating.. I have just realized because i was rotation along Y, X and Z were negate because of the rotation... But it don't know how to solve this yet.

Comment: Also change the order, you should translate then rotate and then scale. Because if you scale first, the translation aso will be scaled and the object will appear at a wrong position.

Comment: And also, make your 3 rotation in one time. Instead of use rotateX, then rotateY and then rotateZ. Create a method that creates the rotation matrix. You get the rotation matrix by multiplying like this : Z * Y * X. Where X, Y and Z are your rotation matrix for each axis. And then, multiply your transformation matrix by the rotation matrix.

Comment: I just changed to a simple float to represent the rotation along the Z axis because it's 2d. I think i am on a better way with the mirror but still struggling ^^

Comment: You want to completely invert the Y axis? Because you can simply multiply your Y position by -1.

Comment: I want to flip th sprite so that he face the direction he is running.